# determine, is cert. store system or physical, having HCERTSTORE handle only

Tags: windows, cryptoapi, certificate-store

let us assume, we have a valid HCERTSTORE handle of opened certificate store. How can we determine - is opened store physical or system?

Restriction 1 - we should use CryptoAPI (C++) only.

Restriction 2 - we've successfully forgotten, what kind of store was used in CertOpenStore() call.

Comment: The restrictions are arbitrary. I don't see a [practical problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to solve. Handles can't be passed around between processes, so one cannot "forget" what it was unless deliberately.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem to solve and, specifically, constraints are artificial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a way to solve this with CryptoAPI and, as the constraint 2 is artificial, don't think it was designed to address this problem. Closeable handles can't be passed around between processes, so one cannot "forget" what it was unless deliberately: the knowledge is right there, in the code that got the handle.

By looking through the function list in the left pane at [CertOpenStore - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I see [`CertGetStoreProperty()`](http://CertGetStoreProperty), but there's only one predefined property, `CERT_STORE_LOCALIZED_NAME_PROP_ID`, which isn't reliable.

Comment: Thanks. I also hadn't seen a way to solve it, that's why i asked. The question is not about "practice" itself, but it helped me to define interface to wrap native certificate store methods, so it's about practice (clearance) for me.